# Xmonad refuses to recompile

Tags: linux, linux-mint, window-manager, xmonad

Recently I've installed Xmonad on mint. It works nicely. Then I create an ".xmonad" directory within my home, and a "xmonad.hs" within that ( ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs ). I use the basic example on the Xmonad website to change my mod key:`

```
import XMonad

main = xmonad defaultConfig
     { modMask = mod4Mask
     , terminal = "urxvt"
     }
```

I log out of Xmonad and run:
     xmonad --recompile
and it passive-aggresivly gives an error about Xmonad not compiling, tha part that caught my eye:

```
ExitFailure 127
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I found that I was getting this error on Ubuntu 14.04 because I needed to install the 'libghc-xmonad-contrib-dev' and 'libghc-xmonad-dev' packages

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a syntax error in your configuration. Compared to http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Doc-Configuring.html it should look like

```
import XMonad

       main = xmonad $ defaultConfig
            { modMask            = mod4Mask
            , terminal           = "urxvt" }
```

Comment: Maybe I did have a syntax error my good sir, sadly though, the problem still seems to linger. D: